# How to use pyqt to achieve the effect of Select-Option addition and deletion

Tags: python, pyqt5, sys, qtcore, qtwidgets

I want to use QT to achieve the effect of Select-Option, support deleting Option by clicking the close button,this is my expected rendering:
[image]

The following is my demo. I want to create a custom Widget insert into the QListWidget to achieve this effect, but the logic of closing the Option seems to be not easy to achieve.
Or am I thinking this way completely wrong?
[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class WID(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WID, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(99, 43))
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border:none;")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.toolButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.label.setText("1234")
        self.toolButton.setText("x")
        

class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Fixed)

        for i in range(0, 3):
            wid = WID()
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
            item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
            self.setItemWidget(item, wid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    listWidget = ListWidget()
    listWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't see any "logic of closing the Option" in that code.

Comment: If this is like the interface on SO for adding tags to a Question, then I think you would also want some kind of QLineEdit or QTextEdit with a QCompleter so user can type new select options. An alternate way to achieve same effect would be to put your WID widgets inside a QHBoxLayout inside a QGroupBox. Add a QSpacer on the right to keep all of your WIDs left justified. You should be able to use addItem() and removeItem() methods to add and remove WIDs.

Comment: @bfris tks, I used `QHBoxLayout.addWidget` which looks a little simpler

Comment: Hi! @musicamante I updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the `QHBoxLayout::addWidget` method to add widgets, and use the `deleteLater` solt to delete the QWidget:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class WID(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WID, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(99, 43))
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border:none;")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.toolButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.label.setText("1234")
        self.toolButton.setText("x")
        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.deleteLater)

class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName("self")
        self.resize(437, 29)
        self.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(-1, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
        
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        for i in range(0, 3):
            self.addWidget()

    def addWidget(self):
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(WID())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    listWidget = ListWidget()
    listWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```